# "Reverse-merge" a branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

Assume I have a branch case-xyz where I do my work for case #xyz, "Implement Hello World."

During development, I add debug outputs etc. which should not be part of the final commit.

Can I do something like the following:

- Branch to case-xyz-debug and commit debug code only there.
- Occasionally merge case-xyz-debug into case-xyz.
- Commit stuff that's supposed to go into the final patch in case-xyz.
- At the end, "reverse-merge" case-xyz-debug, i.e., remove all the changes that came from that branch, independent on when they were merge into case-xyz. In other words, this should be an equivalent of reverting all the merges from case-xyz-debug.

I know that when reverting a merge commit, Git does not forget the merge, i.e., it still thinks you have already merged, so you can only re-merge by reverting the revert. So, it's only necessary that all the changes originally committed in case-xyz-debug are removed, how that is recorded is irrelevant. However, it would be nice if I could also do something like the following:

- git checkout case-xyz
- git checkout case-xyz-done
- git "reverse-merge" case-xyz-debug

because I might want to continue developing/debugging:

- git checkout case-xyz
- change a file
- git commit -am "oops, forgot something"
- git checkout case-xyz-really-done
- git "reverse-merge" case-xyz-debug

I hope my intention is clear. If this can be achieved, but in a totally different way, I'd be happy as well.

Comment: IMHO it's not only difficult to do, but also dangerous. What if you inadvertently added non-debug code in the debug branch? what if someday you want you debugging code back? I would instead clearly add debug statement, and disable them in release code like most of languages do.

Comment: If you're really set on this, you could use `rebase` to remove commits from your debug branch. Do `branch case-xyz-before-rebase` then `rebase case-xyz-done case-xyz -i` and remove or squash your debugging commits. But CharlesB is right, it's more trouble than it's worth. You're better off `grep`ping for debug calls and making sure they're commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I do this sort of thing as part of my normal workflow regularly, via interactive rebasing.  I have commits that include debug logging, temporary testing changes (f.e. thread sleep calls to test timing issues, intentionally thrown exceptions to test error handling code), hardcoded values to make it easier to end-to-end test in my app without having to enter values into the UI, etc.  I keep these sorts of things in isolated commits; by my own convention, if the commit log message is in all caps, it signifies a commit that should not be pushed to the remote.

When I'm ready to "reverse-merge" these changes (remove them), I do so via an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i <id of branch point>
```

And I simply delete the commits that have all caps messages.

(You can actually use this for other purposes, for example reordering them so they are all at the beginning of the branch, which is useful for `git commit --amend`'ing your real work, or reordering them to be at the end, which can be useful when you want to push `branch-point..<id of last real commit>` to the remote, leaving your "debug" commits intact and at the end of the current line of history.)

Knowing what `<id of branch point>` is can be somewhat of a pain; in my workflow, I don't want to rebase my branch onto the end of, f.e. `master`, at the same time that I remove debug commits; for that reason, I keep a local floating tag that I use as a reference point which I simply call `rebase` (which may be confusing, but you can choose to name it whatever you like).  If this seems like too much work, using `` git rebase -i `git merge-base HEAD master` `` might be an option for you.

(I understand the arguments that this is a dangerous practice, but I don't find them to be particularly compelling; there are a million ways you can shoot yourself in the foot with SCM.  You should consider some combination of `git rebase --abort` and `git reflog` to be your "escape hatches" in case you accidentally remove a commit that contained more than your debug code.)

HTH